# How to convert string of MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz format to date in js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to convert strings of fixed format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz` with moment.js or any other library and compare them later on. I've took moment.js as an example, but it doesn't seem to be able to recognize `zzz` pattern even when I remove the patter the conversation `isAfter` doesn't look right anyway.

```
var x = moment('12/30/2014 16:26:31 MSK', "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
var y = moment('12/31/2014 06:46:23 MSK', "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");

console.log(x.isValid()); // false
console.log(y.isValid()); // false
console.log(x.isAfter(y)); // false
console.log(x.isBefore(y)); // false
console.log(x.isSame(y)); // false
  
var xWithoutZZZ = moment('12/30/2014 16:26:31', "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
var yWithoutZZZ = moment('12/31/2014 06:46:23', "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  
console.log(xWithoutZZZ.isValid()); // true
console.log(yWithoutZZZ.isValid()); // true
console.log(xWithoutZZZ.isAfter(yWithoutZZZ)); // true ???? WTF WHY
console.log(xWithoutZZZ.isBefore(yWithoutZZZ)); // false
console.log(xWithoutZZZ.isSame(yWithoutZZZ)); // false
```

Please advice which way to solve this https://jsfiddle.net/yjqsb754/

Comment: what does the zzz in the format stands for?

Comment: as you can see in the date sample `'12/30/2014 16:26:31 MSK'` it's human readable timezone format `MSK`

Comment: to be a bit more precise it's zone id  https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Momemnt js doesn't support ZZZ, simply remove this part from the string and use it normally

```
var x = moment(x.substring(0, x.lastIndexOf(' '));
var y = moment(y.substring(0, y.lastIndexOf(' '));
```